# howto replace document object of a window/iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, object, document, code-injection

I need to inject in an iframe window a document object that I instanciated previously, and I cannot serialize it into a string or a remote url (those are solutions proposed on previous stackoverflow posts), because elements of this document objects are bound to other objects in my code.

How can I do it ?

thanks,
b.

Comment: can you instanciate document object already inside iframe?

Comment: I have no clue what in the world your question is here. Wondering if I am the only one.

Comment: Djko : well that was the last solution I was thinking of: instanciating the object inside the iframe and then modify it, finally inject iframe in main document.
I wanted to make sure that I was not missing something.

Comment: epascarello : in other words : to put a document in a window you have to give the url for it, or when your document is already locally in a string, then you can write into the window this string. 
But when your document is a document object, loaded "in the background" through some XmlHTTPRequest and transformed, linked, ..., then HOW CAN YOU INJECT IT INTO A WINDOW OR IFRAME ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using **`importNode`**:

```
/* Change these: */
var documentToCopy = document,
    iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;

/* Replace current document-element (<html>) with the new one: */
iframeDocument.replaceChild(
    iframeDocument.importNode(documentToCopy.documentElement, true),
    iframeDocument.documentElement
);
```

See **https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode**

Comment: this works well in safari 4, but not in FireFox. I must now admit that I inject svg and xml documents, not simply html ones. Any clues ? Thanks anyway.